# How to structure a LOB application/database for offline mode

Tags: sql-server, lob

I have a line of business application that constantly communicates to the database.  I have a user that wants to operate multiple sites at remote locations all connected back to a central database. This setup is working but due to unreliable network communications the user is now asking for an offline mode.

I use SQL Server for the database server.

My question is what resources are available on the web or what have you done to successfully add offline capabilities to a LOB application.

**Update:** I am using PC clients connected to an unreliable WAN.

Answer (score 1):

What are you talking about handsets to the database or PC's via WAN that is unreliable?  [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) will help if you can have a local (to the client) database that would queue and report back to the main database.

Comment: If you can have a SQL Server local to the PC, then use Service Broker to communicate between the servers.  Since it's queued, you won't have to worry about losing the message.

Answer (score 1):

Merge replication was designed for this sort of thing.  Essentially, you'd set up a local data store on the PC(s) and have that database be a merge subscriber to your server database.